# What is Spoon Sandbox Manager?

Tags: windows-vista, performance

When ever I check Task Manager or Process Explorer, I always see this exe in Task Manager spoon-sandbox.exe and there is always more than one instance running at any given time.

I found that it is located at C:\Program Files\Spoon\3.20.0.8

There are 11 folders with different versions ( 3.xx.y.z).

Description of the exe says its Spoon Sandbox Manager.

I am using Windows Vista Business.

Does any one know what it is, and which process initiates it?

Why I have so many different versions on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [process virtualization tool for .NET apps](http://www.xenocode.com/Technology/). It lets you run a process in a virtual environment so you don't have to do an configuration or matching to the host environment. It was supposed to be a way to deploy .NET apps without having to get people to install the .NET framework that matched the version your app needed.

The company that made it *was* called [Code Systems Corporation](http://www.xenocode.com/) but it's turned in to [Turbo.net](http://www.turbo.net/) and focused a little more on browser virtualization in the cloud.

Some software you're using on your system uses their virtualization engine to launch. You can trace the process tree to try and figure out which end software pieces are using spoon engines.

Answer (score 0):

Some googling suggests that this task is part of the Spoon virtualization application (the Spoon plug-in). This is software that lets you run applications from a server in your browser. More information is at http://www.spoon.net/. The site lists many applications, so you might be able to find out which ones you are running by comparing the applications you use to the list.

I suspect that you have many different folders because different applications require different versions of the plug-in. That's just a guess though.